# dojo dijit.InlineEditBox script type='dojo/connect' throws an error sometimes need to suppress

Tags: dojo, inlineeditbox

So I have a html page which has snippets like this

```
<span dojoType='dijit.InlineEditBox' editor='dijit.form.Textarea' id='actionDetails13' value='Leave admit source entered during Express Registration' autoSave='false' noValueIndicator='[Details]'>  
<script type='dojo/connect' event='onChange' args='value'>  
</script>  
</span>
```

This works just fine in chrome and IE however when the page is very large only internet explorer throws an error

```
DOM Exception: NOT_FOUND_ERR (8)
```

and those particular inlineeditbox will no longer appear.  So perhaps of 1,000 inlineedit boxes 70% will render.

If I comment out the script type='dojo/connect' then no errors are thrown.

I think it is probably some limit of IE but any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the way you connect the onClick-event.

Try it like:

```
<script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click">
    on(registry.byId("button1"), "click", function(){
    console.log("I was clicked!");
    });
</script>
```

Regards, Miriam

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use the code below. It works for me.

```
require([
         "dojo/dom-attr",
         "dojo/on",
         "dojo/domReady!"
         ], function ( domAttr,on) {

           var actionDetails13 = dojo.byId("actionDetails13");

           var handle = on(actionDetails13 , "change", customFunction);

           function customFunction() {
                var actionDetails13Value= domAttr.get("actionDetails13", "value"); 
                //your code
           };
        });
```

Ref:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/connect.html

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom-attr.html